# How to convert a XmlDocument to a XLANGMessage type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, type-conversion

How can I convert a XmlDocument to a XLANGMessage type?
I have tried with below method,
Below two methods throws error  : "Cannot Implicitly convert XmlDocument to XLangMessage...

Any other thoughts, please share.

TRY1--

```
public XLANGMessage convertToXlandMsgFromXml(XmlDocument tempInput)
{
    XLANGMessage sampleOutput;            
    tempInput.Load(@"InputMessage.xml");            
    XLANGMessage sampleOutput = tempInput;            
}
```

TRY2--

```
public class FileStreamFactory : IStreamFactory
{
    string _fname;

    public FileStreamFactory(string fname)
    {
        _fname = fname;
    }

    public Stream CreateStream()
    {
        return new FileStream
               (
                _fname,
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.Read
               );
    }
    }  

    public static void AssignStreamFactoryToPart(XLANGMessage msg)
    {
        IStreamFactory sf = new FileStreamFactory( @"c:\\data.xml" );
        msg[0].LoadFrom( sf );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check this link (last part): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2009/09/10/4-different-ways-to-process-an-xlangmessage-within-an-helper-component-invoked-by-an-orchestration.aspx

Create a custom type e.g. CustomBTXMessage

```
  [Serializable]
    public sealed class CustomBTXMessage : BTXMessage
    {
        public CustomBTXMessage(string messageName, Context context)
            : base(messageName, context)
        {
            context.RefMessage(this);
        }
    }
```

Then you can - create a object from that type and load your xml into the body part.

```
var customBTXMessage = new CustomBTXMessage("XLANGMessage", Service.RootService.XlangStore.OwningContext);
customBTXMessage.AddPart(string.Empty, "Body");
```

I would load the xml document in as stream and than you could load the body part from that stream

```
customBTXMessage[0].LoadFrom(stream);
```

this part of code will return you a XLANGMessage

```
 var responseMessage = customBTXMessage.GetMessageWrapperForUserCode();
```

Good luck.

Jonathan

Comment: I'm trying to use this metod to create an XLANGMessage in a C# unit test. It fails because Service.RootService is null.