# BizTalk server XmlDocument/ xmlString to Schema data

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am stuck in a problem, there may be some better solutions but what I tried and failed is explained below.

[image]

If I remove MessageAssignment component, My projects works perfectly it converts the data and makes a file to my directory.

But as I described in image that my MessageAssignment is setting Message4 as XmlDocument (it can be XML string if better solution provided).

CunstructMessage_1 can cunstruct message2 and message4.
MessageAssignment_1 is setting meesage4 as XmlDocument.
Transform_1 takes message2 as input and results message3(another schema).

**Current Scenario:** is that my map gets message2 data and transforms it.

**Required Scenario:** is that i want my message4(XmlDocument) as a records/data for Message2 (input of transform_1), in other words `message2 = someconvertion(message4);` so my transform_1 gets the updated data and continue transformation.

Comment: Please edit your question with the following details. What message(s) are being constructed in ConstructMessage_1?  What is the message being produced by Transform_1? What message is being sent in Send_1?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking.  What is message4?

Comment: @Johns-305 mesage4 has XmlDocument with message-type: XmlDocument, i mentioned it in my description and image as well.

Comment: You cannot use XmlDocument Typed messaged as Input or Output for a Transform.

Comment: Please review question again i updated it.

Comment: What is not clear is how message4 is being created, where is this xmldocument  coming from?  As Johns has said, you can't use a untyped message as an input as a map, so first you would have to type it by assigning it to a typed message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by similar question on stackoverflow [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114038/1310540), and detailed blog post [**blog link**](http://blog.eldert.net/converting-string-to-xlangmessage/)

Thanks to participants for your time.